# "Retrotemporal" side effects (of \centering, et al.)

Tags: formatting

I solved the original problem in the meantime by trying all commands I found :-), but this could nevertheless be of interest. My style is llcns.

I just wanted to center a few \paragraph headers such that they "jumped out" more. \begin{center} wasn't allowed, \centering also gave a syntax error inside \paragraph. The interesting stuff was when I placed \centering before \paragraph. That worked...too good. The whole subsection *before* it got centered too. "Luckily" my wacko idea of entering a dummy empty unnumbered subsection gave an unwanted vspace, God only knows what further side effects that would have brought, especially in the TOC...

But my obvious question is, how can a TeX command (\centering isn't the only one where I observed this behavior) affect something that happened before it? This runs against all my programmers instincts!

P.S. If you need to know: \paragraph\centerline did the trick.

Comment: please always show an example code. `\paragraph` is a section heading so should just have text and never have a command such as `\centering` in its argument. But in general paragraph settings at _the end_ of the paragraph are used for setting the whole paragraph so if you use \centering mid paragraph it will affect earlier text.

Comment: `\paragraph\centerline` can not possibly do anything useful, With the standard definitions it makes the error `! Argument of \centerline  has an extra }`. Please show a small complete document that shows the issue you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paragraph is broken in to lines based on the settings at the end of a paragraph so if you use `\centering` mid-paragraph it affects the whole paragraph including earlier text.

Here `\centering` is used just before the end of the paragraph but it is all centred.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{Some long text that doesn't break} one \fbox{Some long text that doesn't break}
\fbox{Some long text that doesn't break} two two \fbox{Some long text that doesn't break}
\fbox{Some long text that doesn't break} three three three \fbox{Some long text that doesn't break}
\centering

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note however the first line isn't quite centred as it has a paragraph indent on the left, `\parindent` is set to 0 by `\centering` but it is used too late here to affect the indentation box which has already been added.

---

It is hard to address your comments about `\paragraph`: in the standard styles it is a run-in heading set within the first line of the paragraph so can not be centred.

To have centred paragraph headings you would want to make it a display heading.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Section text
\subsection{Something}
SubSection text
\subsubsection{Other thing}
SubSubSection text
\paragraph{4th level heading} 
Paragraph  text
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the `\paragraph` layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1ex}% %inverting the signs so a display heading
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}}% centering
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Section text
\subsection{Something}
SubSection text
\subsubsection{Other thing}
SubSubSection text
\paragraph{4th level heading} 
Paragraph  text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see - it's no bug, it's a feature. Good to know that indeed commands can effect text that comes before it. (I knew I could have issued a \renewcommand on \paragraph, but being a TeX n00b I refrained from that...Especially as I have only a few of them.)